# How to paste special symbols in PHPDocumentor block in PHP like "*/"?

Tags: php, phpdoc

How to paste similar symbols into PHPDoc block?

- `*/`
- `@`

E.g.:

```
/**
 * Please use these symbol "@" with symbols "*/" as well.
 */
```

Could not find it in [documentation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/).

Comment: check the link, you might get some idea http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [phpdoc.org](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html) manual we can read:

> if you need an actual "@" in your DocBlock's description parts, you should be careful to either ensure it is not the first character on a line, or else escape it ("\@")

Also **New 1.2.0rc1:**

> If you need to use the closing comment "*/" in a DocBlock, use the special escape sequence "{@*}."

```
/**
 * <code>
 * \@require 'config.php'
 * Example comment {@*}
 * </code>
 */
```

Will be rendered as:

```
/**
 * <code>
 * @require 'config.php'
 * Example comment */
 * </code>
 */
```